# Node.js Getting Slave Node Info

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing

OK, so I am creating a node/mongo based CMS. I have the basic framework down. I am wanting to add live stats to the admin panel and I was wondering if I could do the following:

I create slave nodes from the master node using the native Cluster call (v0.6).

```
function start_workers(num_workers){
    for (var i = 0; i < num_workers; i++) { 
        exports.workers[i] = cluster.fork(); 
        console.log('Worker: '+exports.workers[i].pid+' Is Online'); 
    }
}
```

Which spawns X number of nodes. I was wondering can I get stats on each worker I spawn?

for instance:

```
for(var x in workers){
    console.log(workers[x].process.cwd());
}
```

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here..?

Comment: I would like to get stats for each of the nodes that are running. For instance Mem usage, CPU usage, uptime, etc.